# What's the best way to query a count of documents that meet a specific criteria in DocumentDB?

Tags: c#, performance, azure-cosmosdb

Currently I'm using `client.CreateDocumentQuery<...>(...).Where(...).Count()`
But I'm worried that this causes DocumentDB to transmit all of the selected documents over the internet, after which my application counts them on the client-side.

Is there a different query method under the client object that will ensure the DocumentDB performs the count, and returns just the final result?
**Or** is the method I'm using, optimized in this fashion already? (i.e. `IOrderedQueryable`)
**Or** do I need to write a stored procedure, in order to keep the processing on the server-side? If so, how do you reference the count of items from within the JavaScript?

Answer (score 3):

To reduce the amount of data sent back from DocumentDB, you can change the LINQ query to .Select(f => 1).AsEnumerable().Count(). This will get translated to a "SELECT VALUE 1 FROM ..." query which will just send a "1" for every result that matches.

Another change that will make this faster is to change the MaxItemCount by setting FeedOptions.MaxItemCount = -1 (maximum). So something like

```
client.CreateDocumentQuery<..>(
        collectionLink, 
        new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 })
    .Where(..)
    .Select(f => 1)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Count()
```

An alternate approach is using stored procedures to perform count - you can use an existing library like DocumentDB Lumenize: https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-lumenize

The pros and cons of each approach - the former is better if you collection is throughput bottlenecked, and the latter is better for latency since you'll just send back the count vs. sending back 1s and summing them up client side.

Comment: I'm surprised that the benefit of using secondary copies overcomes the latency of sending potentially thousands of "1"s. Does your recommendation only apply when transferring within the same data center or do you think it still applies for transfer out of the data center?

Comment: The stored procedure is certainly better for latency - the advantage is with throughput. Using queries means that you can utilize all secondaries for reads.

Comment: So if this request were being made multiple times or competing with other parallel operations, this is favored but ad-hoc or on a less than fully loaded system, a stored procedure might be better?

Comment: Great solution. The recommended SELECT VALUE COUNT on the Cosmos db docs just doesn't help with filtering when doing COUNT.